What is a good way to manage the connections of multiple chat rooms in a netty environment?
Currently, I am developing a chat application using Netty.
I am worried about 'broadcasting messages' to users who exist in the chat room.
Here are the methods I've come up with.
1. Use Map with channels as value using roomId as the key
new CurrentHashMap<String,Set<Channel>>
2. using DefaultChannelGroup
val defaultChannelGroup = DefaultChannelGroup(GlobalEventExecutor.INSTANCE)

It's easy to read and write about channels, but I can't divide the channels by chat room.
Apart from that, I know you can use Redis pub/sub to implement a chat server, but I don't know which implementation part of netty to go into.
How should I manage and use the status of the channel when implementing a NetEasy chat server?

Couple of suggestion
Your idea to create a ConcurrentHashMap<String, Set>, where the key is the roomId and the value is a Set of Channels seems good.
For broadcasting, iterate over the set of channels for a given room and write the message to each channel.
Use DefaultChannelGroup within a Map<String, DefaultChannelGroup> structure, where each roomId maps to a distinct DefaultChannelGroup. This will help in the room-based partitioning.

You can optionally use the Redis Pub/Sub to offload the message broadcasting logic to Redis which simplifies the Netty server's architecture and makes it scalable. So basically use Redis Pub/Sub for message distribution and Netty to handle connections. Upon receiving a message, publish it to Redis, and have each Netty server subscribe to relevant channels.
Maintain channel membership in Redis or locally with the ConcurrentHashMap or DefaultChannelGroup methods, syncing when necessary.
